# In Python, what is the difference between pass and return

Tags: python

I have seen some code in Pinax and other django apps that instead of pass, an empty return statement is used. What is the difference and would it have any effect on, for example, the django code below that I am running? The code is a signal method that automatically saves the hashtags into taggit Tag objects for a tweet object.

I saw a question here about whether having or not having a return statement in PHP makes a difference in the interpreted bytecode, but I am not sure if it is relevant to Python.

```
import re
TAG_REGEX = re.compile(r'#(?P<tag>\w+)')

def get_tagged(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    """
    Automatically add tags to a tweet object.
    """
    if not instance:
        return # will pass be better or worse here?
    post = instance
    tags_list = [smart_unicode(t).lower() for t in list(set(TAG_REGEX.findall(post.content)))]
    if tags_list:
        post.tags.add(*tags_list)
        post.save()
    else:
        return # will a pass be better or worse here?
post_save.connect(get_tagged, sender=Tweet)
```

Comment: e.g. you cannot define a function/... stump without anything in it. Pass is a noop /nullop

Answer (score 89, accepted):

```
if not instance:
    return # will pass be better or worse here?
```

Worse.  It changes the logic.  `pass` actually means: Do nothing.  If you would replace `return` with `pass` here, the control flow would continue, changing the semantic of the code.

The purpose for `pass` is to create empty blocks, which is not possible otherwise with Python's indentation scheme.  For example, an empty function in C looks like this:

```
void foo()
{
}
```

In Python, this would be a syntax error:

```
def foo():
```

This is where `pass` comes handy:

```
def foo():
    pass
```

Comment: wouldn't 
`def foo(): 
    return` 
do the same thing as `def foo(): pass`?

Comment: @JayWalker In that specific case; yes, they would do the same.

Answer (score 44):

This illustrates some earlier answers.

```
def p():
  "Executes both blocks."
  if True:
    print(1)
    pass
  if True:
    print(2)
    pass

def r():
  "Executes only the first block."
  if True:
    print(1)
    return
  if True:
    print(2)
    return
```

Comment: The accepted answer best captures the "spirit" of the difference, but this answer does a great job of explaining the functional difference.  :)

Answer (score 27):

[Return](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement) exits the current function or method.  [Pass](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-pass-statement) is a null operation and allows execution to continue at the next statement.

Answer (score 2):

```
if not instance:
    return # will pass be better or worse here?
```

a `pass` would continue the execution of the method. A `return` would terminate the execution of the method. Regarding the following lines, you want to put `return` here.

```
else:
    return # will a pass be better or worse here?
```

here it wouldn't make a difference. Even removing the whole two lines wouldn't change anything.

But anyway, imagine you would elaborate the method further. It's better to choose the right flow from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a comment than an answer, but it won't fit as a comment.

```
if not instance:
    return # will pass be better or worse here?
```

As explained in the accepted answer, `pass` would be incorrect.

```
else:
    return # will a pass be better or worse here?
```

Here, since we are at the end of the function, `pass` would do the same thing: nothing. Even better would be to leave off the `else` clause entirely, since there is nothing to do. (It's true that "explicit is better than implicit" in the Zen, but this rarely applies to explicitly doing nothing - it's clear what happens in the `else` case, to anyone who actually even wonders about it in the first place.)

(It's also not clear why you rename `instance` to `post` within the function - you could just change the parameter name? - or what the `sender` argument is supposed to be for. Oh, and you don't actually need to convert a `set` to a `list` to iterate over it in a list comprehension. :) )

Answer (score 1):

```
if not instance:
    return # will pass be better or worse here?
```

It'll be worse, cause in that case it'll execute the following line of codes in your defined function even when the there is no `instance`.

`pass` has it's own essence, it is used to define empty blocks, it shouldn't be considered as an alternative to a `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

See the python docs on [pass](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-pass-statement) and [return](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement). In your current code there isn't really a difference (in fact, I would leave the `else` away entirely).

The difference is mainly in the semantics: `pass` can be used where a statement is syntactically required, but not (yet) needed. On the other hand, `return` fulfills a sort of contract for a function, providing an explicit result.

Comment: I read the docs before posting, but didn't really understand this: "In a generator function, the return statement is not allowed to include an expression_list. In that context, a bare return indicates that the generator is done and will cause StopIteration to be raised." Now it is clear it simply means "exit the flow" ;) Thanks!